# Debug Symfony2 projects in PHPStorm

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, phpstorm

I have a problem in debugging symfony2 applications in PHPStorm with xdebug because of `Request::createFromGlobals()` method. All other project debugs well.

The problem occurs, when the execution process meets the invocation of this method, the debugger just turns off without any error and the page is rendered.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: I've decided to use php+apache that is in MacBook by default, only setup it a little and it works. Still don't know what was wrong with MAMP+Symfony2

Answer (score 1):

Try change app_dev.php to:

```
...
//$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
...
```

Comment: No - unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: I did this (just changed the loader to autoload.php) and it worked for me. What a nightmare!

Comment: Didn't think on this, good point, but it didn't work to me either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with PhpStorm 7. The solution was to go into project settings and select Servers under PHP. Choose the server you are using (localhost in my case) and explicitly setup the directory mapping in the symfony project folder.