# phpstorm xdebug with a symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug a symfony2 application with xdebug and phpstorm.

My local development environment is Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 and Xdebug version is 2.2.7

I have this working on another php (not symfony2) projects with the following guides:

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

When I execute the bookmarlet to set the cookie and start debugging this symfony2 project phpstorm detects the incoming connection (which I accept), but nothing else happens. It doesn't stop in any breakpoint.

I have the symfony2 phpstorm plugin. I tried to disable it and get nothing as well.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639453/844451) looked good to me, but it didn't the trick either

Last thing I tried is to change the Servers debug configuration, disabling path mappings. This way phpstorm starts debugging, but it breaks in app_dev.php file instead of any breakpoint I have set.

I am stuck here, any idea would be appreacite

**UPDATE**

More information I didn't mention:

- I am using firefox I am trying to debug dev environment
- Breakpoints are in an action in controller of my own, not vendor ones.

**UPDATE**

Here is my xdebug configuration

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

Comment: which environment are you trying to debug? prod or dev? And what files are you set breakpoints in? your custom or ones provided by vendors?

Comment: Thanks @TomaszMadeyski I am trying to debug dev environment, breakpoinst are in actions in a controller of my own. I am updating my question with this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a mapping problem. The following are the steps which did the trick

1. Disable path mapping under Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers > uncheck "Use path mappings
2. Start debugging
3. The famous “Remote file path ‘path/to/script/on/the/server.php’ is not mapped to any file path in project“ finally appears
4. Then I could follow the Troubleshooting section in [official guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) setting up path mappings

Hope this helps to anyone else

Answer (score 10):

I don't know which browser you are using, but, using Chrome, I use the Xdebug helper extension.

Once the extension is installed, right click on it > options and select PHPStorm as IDE.

Then, start listening for connection on PHPStorm using the button near the debug one.

**EDIT**:

Here is my configuration of XDebug:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.collect_params = 1
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

Are you sure XDebug is properly installed on your machine ?

When in `PHPStorm` > `Run` > `Edit Configurations...`, add a PHP Web Application debugging profile and fill it this way:

- **Name**: Acme Project
- **Server**: apache2 (you might need to add yours - name, port, adresse, debugger)
- **Start URL** : /app_dev.php
- **Browser**: Default

Press OK and you're done !

Comment: Thank you @Rybus, that is a good one. But I'd like to keep using firefox. I am updating my question with browser information as well.

Comment: FYI. Just tried that with Chrome and it is not working. Not even the incoming connection appears, although I think this maybe is because I did previously

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide you new details about my configuration ;)

Comment: Thanks. As I mention in the question I debug with phpstorm and xdebug any others projects except this one, so xdebug is properly working. I updated with my xdebug configuration. I am going to check with yours now, I am only aware about the port configuration, but let's see.

EDIT: got nothing at all

Comment: Do you have anything in your log files ? (Apache)

Comment: I don't. But I have it working now as I use to, so I can keep working on this :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue which again proved to be a mapping problem, debugging a Symfony 2 project remotely using PHPStorm.

If PHPStorm can't map the src file locations, it will break on the first line of code in app_dev.php (if you've set 'Break on first line') but then continue straight through any break points set in /src (e.g. Controllers, Models, etc.) and doesn't flag any error.

1. Go to Setting -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers
2. Select your server in the middle-left pane (or add using '+')
3. Check 'Use path mappings (select if the server is remote or symlinks are used)'
4. Add mappings such that /app, /src and /web are mapped.  These can be individual mappings, but it's better if possible to set a higher level mapping on / which covers them all.

Once PHPStorm can map these paths, it stops and breakpoints and meaningful debugging can begin.

Comment: Thank you so much @stanhope!! I was trying to figure it out for about 2 hours so far! It work like a charm. Be careful, mapping just the `app.php` file will run through it and will never go to actual controller but will finish the debugging session.

Comment: For point 4 can you please add an example of local and remote mapping? As entry points are in /web ( so request / -> web/ ) what do you map the other locations with? I have used xdebug several times but in a project i am using now it is not able to work. It reaches app_dev.php if i enable break at first line but never stops at breakpoints. I have the symfony plugin installed on phpstorm

Answer (score 2):

If you find that PHPStorm keeps asking for mappings try and create a mapping at the highest level of the project as @stanhope mentioned, that should be enough.

My first mapping was incorrectly set to the app_dev.php file in /web which meant that the IDE kept asking me for mappings to files in vendor directories.

**e.g. /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had to comment out the loading of class cache (symfony 2.7). I did it temporarily in the `web/app_dev.php`

```
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
```

Otherwise the debugging took place in `bootstrap.php.cache` or breakpoints did not work.